# What does this mean in "crontab -e"?

Tags: cron

When I run `crontab -e`, I see this bit:

> Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system daemon's notion of time and timezones.

How to convert *the cron's system daemon's notion of time and timezones* to something I understand or is there some way I can work it out?

I don't keep my machine on all the time and so I would like to set a **daily** time when my machine is most likely to be on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: the introductory comments one sees when running `crontab -e` include these words:

> Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system daemon's notion of time and timezones.

What that actually means is not clear to me that is why I asked the question.

So I ran `crontab -e` to have this line:

```
45 16 * * * touch /home/dbk/Desktop/$(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).txt
```

What I'm asking `cron` to do is to create a file with the current time as prefix and `.txt` as extension and to do this at `16:45 h` *based on the cron's system daemon's notion of time and timezones*.

Whenever the file is created, I can compare the prefix of the file with the "date modified" and thereby come to know what time `cron` ran the job.

As it so happens, `cron` ran the job at `16:45 IST` which is my local time.

Answer (score 0):

- You can add

  ```
  * * * * * date > /tmp/current_time.txt
  ```

  and see what time cron is running with. Cron will use local time so it should (by default) show `UTC`.
- See `/etc/default/cron` if you want to change it. It will show `TZ=UTC` (by default).

Comment: Okay, you're suggesting I run the date command but why `* * * * *`? Please explain! This will be my first cron attempt.

Comment: I did that and got `Wed Mar 12 18:21:01 IST 2014` which is my local time. So, if I want to run a job everyday at 17:00:00 what should I use?